# How can add a wordpress insert in a jquery function?

Tags: jquery, sql, wordpress

I wrote a this code under wordpress and I would like that at the click of my link, the link does not appear anymore and my query wordpress is launched.

I have add

```php
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?>
```

in my header.php file in the  section.

and here is my code :

```php
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('a#valid').click(function(){
    jQuery('#valid').hide();
    $wpdb->insert($table, $data, $format);
    echo "Merci $userName d'avoir validé le module <b> $pageActuelle </b>!";

});
});
</script>
<?php

global $wpbd;
$table = $wpdb->prefix.'modulesCours';
$pageActuelle = get_the_title();
$user_id = get_current_user_id( );
$userName = $current_user->user_nicename;
$pageUrl = get_page_link();

$data = array(
    'module'=> $pageActuelle,
    'user'=> $user_id,
    'page'=> $pageUrl,);
    $format = array('%s', '%d');

$requete = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user = $user_id AND module like '%$pageActuelle' AND page like '%$pageUr'";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($requete);

if ($result != null) {
    echo "Désolé $userName mais vous aviez déjà validé le module <b> $pageActuelle </b>!";
    }
else {
    ?>
    <a href="#" id="valid">Valider le module</a>
    <?php
}
```

this :

```php
 $wpdb->insert($table, $data, $format);
```

seem don't work.
But work without jQuery

thank you !

Comment: It looks like your script section at the top is trying to mix js logic with php logic.

Comment: yes but i don't know how to do ....

Comment: Because you cannot mix the two.  You can generate javascript logic with PHP, but you cannot directly mix the two.  PHP runs on the server, returns the page to the client browser, where the javascript then executes.

Comment: ok thank you i'll try this monday :)

Comment: To request the insert from browser javascript without doing a full page load you'll probably want to use AJAX. There should be plenty of how-tos on the web, and maybe even some specific examples that match what you want to do. Or (particularly if you have trouble with them) you could submit a specific question about that, or a broader question about how to accomplish your overall goal.